# How does 4G LTE work faster than any ordinary Internet connection

Tags: computer-networks

How is 4G LTE faster than any ordinary internet connection? What is the mechanism behind it?

Comment: What do you mean by “ordinary”? Some people consider 4G to be an ordinary internet connection. Technology marches on, today's networks are faster than yesterday's. Regarding how LTE works, what do you want to know that isn't in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTE_(telecommunication))?

Comment: Okay thanks for correcting me and guiding me

Comment: I suggest to re-ask this on http://superuser.com .

Comment: Landline Internet is just very bad in USA. In Romania the "ordinary" connection using a landline fiber optic/landline phone is about 1 GBPS, which is larger than 4G LTE. And for 1 GBPS connection people pay about 20 dollars/month. So it is just very different quality from the providers. Internet in the USA is expensive and just very bad....